# scroll div hide/show using id/class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to hide div when scrolling from bottom to top and from top to bottom last it should show div but some issue occurs one way or the other image is look like this-

[image]

The method i am using is this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

        if ($(this).scrollTop()>0)
        {
            $("div.nav-down").fadeOut();
        }
        else
        {
            $("div.nav-down").fadeIn();
        }
    });
```

Comment: are you sure your `$(window)scroll(` is working
If not try this `window.onscroll`

Comment: And what kind of issue you are getting... please provide some of them.

Comment: actually i want to show div on bottom and after hitting scroll for top it should hide which is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it with the animate function rather than the fadeOut and fadeIn one (it only appears when on the absolute bottom of the page):

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
 var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
 if(scrollTop  + $(this).height() == $(document).height() ) {
  $(".nav-down").stop().animate({
   opacity: "1",
      height: "50px"
  });
 } else {
  $(".nav-down").stop().animate({
   opacity: "0",
      height: "0px"
  });
 }
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}

.nav-down {
  float: left;
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.lorum {
  float: left;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="lorum">Example text to make it able to scroll up and down: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque augue augue, vestibulum nec convallis vitae, feugiat vel dui. Pellentesque consectetur justo magna. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et auctor ex varius sit amet. Etiam et vulputate nulla. Donec ac leo</div>
  <div class="nav-down">test</div>
  <div class="lorum">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque augue augue, vestibulum nec convallis vitae, feugiat vel dui. Pellentesque consectetur justo magna, et auctor ex varius sit amet. Etiam et vulputate nulla. Donec ac leo</div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: yes its working as expected `$(window).scroll(function(){
 var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
 if(scrollTop > 0 ) {
  $(".nav-down").stop().animate({
   opacity: "1",
      height: "50px"
  });
 } else {
  $(".nav-down").stop().animate({
   opacity: "0",
      height: "0px"
  });
 }
});` but i want to hide when scroll from bottom to top and when top to bottom it should show as i used this scrollTop > 0 then it worked from top to bottom but from bottom to top it still remains

Comment: I just made a small edit, so it only appears when at the very bottom, I dont know if you noticed.

Comment: if(scrollTop  + $(this).height() == $(document).height() )

Comment: yeah it works but it hides rather than shows and only one time it is hiding after checking back it is hidden for good.

Comment: this is probably because you are not able to scroll down anymore?

Comment: i can but it hides for good the div it should show from top to bottom and hides from bottom to top.

Comment: Maby I was editing my answer (because of an error) as you were copying the code... try to copy it once more and let me know should you still have this issue.

Comment: its not working www.bhkwise.com/Home/Report1?HousingName=Silverglades-ITC-Laburnum&hid=ZALLNPPPB try on this page and tell if it works i will be grateful sir

Comment: this worked `if(scrollTop < 725) {
                    $(".nav-down").stop().animate({
                        opacity: "0",
                        height: "0px"
                    });
                } 
                else {
                    //alert('1');
                    console.log(scrollTop + 'dang1');
                    $(".nav-down").stop().animate({
                        opacity: "1",
                        height: "50px"
                    });
                }`

Comment: Glad you found the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let isScrolling = null;
const ponyElement = document.querySelector('#pony');

window.addEventListener("scroll", e => {

  if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
    ponyElement.classList.remove("hide");
  }else{
    ponyElement.classList.add("hide");
  }

});
```

```css
*{
  padding: 0em;
  margin: 0em;
}

html{
  background: skyblue;
}

#pony{
  width: 10em;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: -3em;
  left: 1em;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

#pony.hide{
  bottom: -100vh;
}


#long{
 height: 100em;
}
```

```html
<img id='pony' class='hide' src='https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/1c/b7/ca/1cb7caa5fe69d5210407b41b15297ff3.jpg' />

<div id='long'></div>
```

If I misunderstanding, please tell me

Comment: yes but i want to hide it when scroll on above from the bottom and to show when reached at the bottom every time, in your code it pops up when ever i stop scroll

Comment: I just update the code, hope this time I can get it right :P